# Intersecting projective variety by $\dim(X) + 1$ hyperplanes, infinite field requirement

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I've been going through Ravi Vakil's *The Rising Sea* FOAG for self-study, and just finished Exercise 11.3.C which shows a number of useful facts regarding the intersection of closed projective varieties with hypersurfaces over four parts (a) - (d). Most interesting to me is parts (c) and (d) which state

> [Suppose $X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_k$ is a closed subset of dimension $r$...] Show further that there is an intersection of $r + 1$ nonempty hypersurfaces missing $X$.  ... If $k$ is infinite, show that there is a codimension $r + 1$ linear subspace missing $X$. (The key step: show that there is a hyperplane not containing any generic point of a component of $X$.)

and

> If $k$ is an infinite field, show that there is an intersection of $r$ hyperplanes meeting $X$ in a finite number of points. (We will see in Exercise 12.4.C that if $k = \overline{k}$, for “most” choices of these $r$ hyperplanes, this intersection is reduced

respectively. From the last sentence in (d), it becomes somewhat obvious that we want to make use of Krull's Principal ideal theorem to cut out $X$ by "good" hyperplanes, ensuring we reduce dimension by 1 each time. So in a hand-wavey argument, if $X = V_+(I)$ for homogeneous $I$, we first pick $f_1$ not a zerodivisor in $k[x_0, \dots, x_n] / I$ and $ \mathfrak{p}_1 $ minimal among those primes containing $f$. Then take some $f_2$ thats a non-zerodivisor on $k[x_0, \dots, x_n] / (I + (f_1))$  and so forth. My first question is

1. How is this related to regular sequences (c.f. §8.4.4 in Vakil)? Vakil mentions when $M = A$, regular sequences give good models of complete intersections, so do we simply want a complete intersection of $r+1$ hypersurfaces so that the intersection with $X$ is empty?

and the second question, more aligned with the problem itself, is

2. Why is it necessary for $k$ to be an infinite field in order to ensure the non-zerodivisor $f_i$ picked are linear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's not really related to regular sequences in any interesting conceptual way. You do want a complete intersection of $r+1$ hypersurfaces so the intersection with $X$ is empty, but the complete intersection condition is a consequence of missing $X$: the thing you get by intersecting $r+1$ nonempty hypersurfaces must be a complete intersection if it misses $X$, as if the intersection has any components of codimension $< r+1$, then those components must intersect $X$ by the projective intersection theorem (exercise 11.3.F).
2. It may be that every linear form $f_i$ with coefficients in the base field intersects your variety: for instance, consider a curve $X$ in $\Bbb P^2_k$ for $k$ finite which passes through every closed point. Then there is no linear variety of codimension two which misses $X$, since that's a rational point not on $X$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Geometry over finite fields is a bit mystical to me so I hadn't even considered a curve going through every point on $\mathbb{P}^2_k$. I suppose this is why the 'sufficiently high degree' part is necessary

Comment: Well, they're not every point, just every rational point - you're right that this can be a little unintuitive.